# Xcode: How do I save a pdf locally and recall it prior to checking for the file again?

Tags: ios, xcode6

I've built an app for my daughter's school's PTO group and parents.  It's an informational app that helps parents stay informed with events and activities.  Currently, the pdf is located online (using a static hyperlink on Box) and takes approximately 10-15 seconds to load/show.  This feels like an eternity.
    I'd now like to add functionality to improve the UX.  Namely, when the app opens for the first time, it should fetch the pdf and then save it to the device.  Subsequent loads of the view controller should then check for a local copy of the pdf first, display that, then check the hyperlink and download a new copy in the background, then display the new version (in case it's been updated).
    Here's one of the *.m files:

```
#import "DZFeaturedViewController.h"

@interface DZFeaturedViewController ()
@end

@implementation DZFeaturedViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidLoad

{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://app.box.com/shared/static/r084wwismdq9mmiok3n9.pdf"];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView loadRequest:requestURL];
    [super viewDidLoad];   
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [webView reload];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I researched Core Data and that seemed like a heavy implementation for a small data storage solution like this.  I looked through the forums here for something that would work and I got close in some threads, but not exactly the solution I needed.  This should be straightforward (this is my first app so I'm pretty new to coding) and it's an embarrassing part of the app experience that I'm trying to correct.
    Any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Does the PDF ever change? If not, just embed it as a resource. If so, either use built-in URL caching tools in Cocoa, or just store in the documents directory.

Comment: Currently, with this code, every time the view controller is loaded, the PDF will refresh with a blink (un-intentional effect) after the app has again loaded the hyperlink.  URL caching looked daunting from some of the code I looked at.  Storing in the documents directory sounds straightforward.  Can you please point me in the right direction there?

Comment: Before you go down that route, one question: Does the PDF every change? Because if it doesn't, it is much simpler and better to just embed it in the app.

Comment: Also - if Box is handling their HTTP caching headers right, iOS should already be loading the PDF from cache if nothing has changed.

Comment: I see where you're going and I'm sorry to be difficult here but yeah, it changes about once a month.  So I'll need to check the save locatio for a file, view it if it exists, and grab it from the hyperlink regardless of if it does or does not exist, save it. Load it to view. Then when the app loads, after a restart, it will check for the saved file, find it, load it, etc. the end result is an improved customer experience because of the drastically improved loading time for each pdf. :). Sincerely appreciate the help here!  Thank you

Comment: That shouldn't matter. If box does their caching headers right, it should only fetch when the file has changed.

Comment: Maybe Box isn't doing it right.  the App currently shows a blank WebView initially when the View Controller is first called on the screen.  It then fetches the PDF and displays it.  when moving through the Tab Bar Items (also linking to hyperlink PDFs or actual website urls) it will initially show a blank WebView then fetch the PDF (or website) and display it.  When moving back and forth between Tab Bar Items that have already been loaded, it still has the PDF (or website) shown, and then a blink that refreshes the screen with updated information.

Comment: How would I save that pdf (don't need to save the websites) after fetching, for loading after the app has been shutdown or restarted.  Upon initial loading of the app, I'd like it to search for a saved PDF (from a previous fetch) first, load that, then fetch and overwrite the saved PDF with the updated PDF.  Regardless if the PDF changed, I'm ok with not checking and simply overwriting every time.  Not 100% efficient, but the user experience is not affected noticeably if I don't have a check in place.